# Efficient quaternions to Euler transformation

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I'm using the following Python function to convert quaternions to Euler angles:

```
import math

def quaternion_to_euler_angle(w, x, y, z):
    ysqr = y * y

    t0 = +2.0 * (w * x + y * z)
    t1 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (x * x + ysqr)
    X = math.degrees(math.atan2(t0, t1))

    t2 = +2.0 * (w * y - z * x)
    t2 = +1.0 if t2 > +1.0 else t2
    t2 = -1.0 if t2 < -1.0 else t2
    Y = math.degrees(math.asin(t2))

    t3 = +2.0 * (w * z + x * y)
    t4 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (ysqr + z * z)
    Z = math.degrees(math.atan2(t3, t4))

    return X, Y, Z
```

I would like to transform a Pandas DataFrame, which has columns "w", "quat_x", "quat_y" and "quat_z", to Eueler angles. Currently, I'm iterating over each row of the DataFrame using a for loop and call the `quaternion_to_euler_angle()` function on each row. This is very slow because I have more than 400'000 rows.

Is there a more efficient way to do it? For example, I could pass the DataFrame (or inidividual Series) to `quaternion_to_euler_angle()` but then the problem is to change `quaternion_to_euler_angle()` so that it can handle DataFrames instead of integers.

Comment: Can you add some sample data, 5 rows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could leverage vectorized [`NumPy ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) instead of their `math` module counterparts that work on entire array data and still have minimal change(s) -

```
import numpy as np

def quaternion_to_euler_angle_vectorized1(w, x, y, z):
    ysqr = y * y

    t0 = +2.0 * (w * x + y * z)
    t1 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (x * x + ysqr)
    X = np.degrees(np.arctan2(t0, t1))

    t2 = +2.0 * (w * y - z * x)
    t2 = np.where(t2>+1.0,+1.0,t2)
    #t2 = +1.0 if t2 > +1.0 else t2

    t2 = np.where(t2<-1.0, -1.0, t2)
    #t2 = -1.0 if t2 < -1.0 else t2
    Y = np.degrees(np.arcsin(t2))

    t3 = +2.0 * (w * z + x * y)
    t4 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (ysqr + z * z)
    Z = np.degrees(np.arctan2(t3, t4))

    return X, Y, Z
```

So, the only replacements were :

```
math.degrees <-> np.degrees
math.atan2   <-> np.arctan2
math.asin    <-> np.arcsin
```

And `np.where` for vectorized checks and assignments.

Hence, we get our vectorized solution like so -

```
# For df.columns = ['w', 'quat_x', 'quat_y', 'quat_z']
X,Y,Z = quaternion_to_euler_angle_vectorized1(*df.values.T)

# If needed as a dataframe output 
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'X':X,'Y':Y,'Z':Z})
```

Timings on `400,000` rows -

```
In [55]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.rand(400000,4)
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(a)
    ...: df.columns = ["w", "quat_x", "quat_y" , "quat_z"]

In [56]: %timeit quaternion_to_euler_angle_vectorized1(*df.values.T)
1 loops, best of 3: 70.6 ms per loop
```

**Optimization #1**

Use `np.clip` to replace double `np.where` -

```
def quaternion_to_euler_angle_vectorized2(w, x, y, z):
    ysqr = y * y

    t0 = +2.0 * (w * x + y * z)
    t1 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (x * x + ysqr)
    X = np.degrees(np.arctan2(t0, t1))

    t2 = +2.0 * (w * y - z * x)

    t2 = np.clip(t2, a_min=-1.0, a_max=1.0)
    Y = np.degrees(np.arcsin(t2))

    t3 = +2.0 * (w * z + x * y)
    t4 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (ysqr + z * z)
    Z = np.degrees(np.arctan2(t3, t4))

    return X, Y, Z
```

Timings on same data -

```
In [70]: %timeit quaternion_to_euler_angle_vectorized2(*df.values.T)
10 loops, best of 3: 65.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 10):

A more compact way is to use `Rotation` from `scipy.spatial.transform`:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

rot = Rotation.from_quat(quat_df)
rot_euler = rot.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)
euler_df = pd.DataFrame(data=rot_euler, columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that Scipy uses real last format for quaternions. There are also no flags or parameters to set the order of the quaternions. You have to make your own shim.