# Visualizing quaternions in python

Tags: python, data-visualization, quaternions

I mounted an IMU on a drone which collected quaternion data (w,x,y,z) every 0.1s. Now i would like to compare the quaternion data to the actual drone orientation (video data).

So i would like to create some sort of box object that shows the orientation based on the quaternion data. I implemented the following tutorial which converts the quaternions to euler for visualization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S77r-P6YxAU&list=PLGs0VKk2DiYwEo-k0mjIkWXlkrJWAU4L9&index=21

Is there a way to directly visualize quaternion data, without converting it to euler first? I feel like this should be possible, but i am not sure how.

Comment: Quaternions are a 4D data structure, so any visualization would require converting it to a 3D world. All visualizations would be somewhat abstract so the question is rather in what aspects or for what purpose you want them to be visualized, and for whom.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Good point! Maybe, i should re-formulate my question: is there any easy way to visualize quaternions in to a 3D space? Because, i feel like the code used in the tutorial could be simplified somehow.

Comment: I would personally think that converting the quaternions to Euler angles is indeed the most straightforward and most intuitive visualization. It is a non-trivial mathematical process, but you can abstract that away in a function. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) has a great example of this, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56207448/6486738), and there are many python libraries that could convert this for you if you don't want to do it yourself, like numpy/scipy.