# How to compute Euler angles from Quaternion form?

Tags: python, quaternions, euler-angles

I am trying to use the Quaternion form instead of rotation matrices.

I already trained my model, but when I need to test the model, I must compute Euler angles from the Quaternion form as this person did with [computing Euler angles from rotation matrices](https://github.com/papagina/RotationContinuity/blob/758b0ce551c06372cab7022d4c0bdf331c89c696/Inverse_Kinematics/code/tools.py#LL413C1-L413C68).

For example, the output in Quaternion form for B = batch_size = 2 (-> Bx4) is :

```
tensor([[ 0.0725, -0.0645,  0.0308,  0.9948],
        [-0.5235, -0.2456,  0.0824,  0.8117]], device='cuda:0')
```

And, the output in rotation matrices form for B = batch_size = 2 (-> Bx3x3) :

```
tensor([[[ 0.9933, -0.0871,  0.0755],
         [ 0.0850,  0.9959,  0.0316],
         [-0.0779, -0.0250,  0.9966]],

        [[ 0.7244, -0.0551, -0.6871],
         [ 0.2493,  0.9503,  0.1866],
         [ 0.6427, -0.3065,  0.7021]]], device='cuda:0')
```

**Note:** this is output for batch_size; it is not one frame or one image.

Could you help me with how we can compute Euler angles from Quaternion form?

Comment: I would recommend this paper [1], the authors detail conventions when using 3d rotations and and provide a codebase for reference [2].

[1] https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0965-0393/23/8/083501/meta
[2] https://github.com/marcdegraef/3Drotations

Comment: you could try adapting from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56207448), which contains the basic equations for quaternion to euler transformaition